# Sum of squared variables equals Chi-squared implies that the variables are standard normal?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, skew-normal-distribution

It is known that if iid $Y_1,...,Y_n \sim N(0,1)$ than $\sum_i Y_i^2 \sim \chi^2_n$.

However, if we know that (independent) $Y_1,...,Y_n$ have $\sum_i Y_i^2 \sim \chi^2_n$, can we say that $Y_1,...,Y_n \sim N(0,1)$?

Comment: If you assume the $Y_i$ are iid, then you can conclude that the $|Y_i|$ have half-Normal ($\chi_1$) distributions.

Comment: This seems inconsistent with what Tomas Ferenci said about mixtures of $\chi_1$ and $- \chi_1$. What am I missing? However, I do think that I'm assuming that the $Y_i$ are iid.

Comment: When the distribution of $Y$ is a mixture of a distribution $F$ with non-negative support and its negative $\tilde F,$ the distribution of $|Y|$ is $F.$

Comment: That makes sense. I think I missed the absolute value bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The sum of independent $\chi$-squares is $\chi$-squared, so $Y_i\sim\chi_1$ will work, and $\chi_1\neq\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$.

Comment: What about if we know that Y can take both positive and negative values?

Comment: @Dave Well, you could simply use the mixture distribution of $\chi_1$ and $-\chi_1$. I don't think it has a special name, the bottomline is that it will work, as squaring will of course make it the same as the square of $\chi_1$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: @Dave Ah, one more thing: if you use $1/2$-$1/2$ as the mixing weights, you just get back the standard normal :) So the approach is correct, but use any other mixing weight.

Comment: @jsk Yes, but I have written $Y_i\sim \chi_1$ (not $\chi_1^2$, i.e., I meant $\chi$-distribution).

Comment: Hold on...I just saw that you did the chi distribution, not chi-squared. Isn't $\chi_1$ just N(0,1)?

Comment: @Dave No! Without any further consideration: $\chi$-distributions have the support of only the positive real numbers, so it can't be $\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$.

Comment: @Dave If $Z\sim N(0,1)$, then $|Z|\sim\chi_1$. Re: "What about if we know that Y can take both positive and negative values?" another example other than mixtures; consider $X\sim \chi_1$ and $Y=X$ if $X>1$ and $Y=-X$ otherwise. Then $Y$ takes positive and negative values and $Y$ is non-normal but $Y^2\sim\chi^2_1$.

Answer (score 3):

One other interesting example is the [skew-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution).  Based on the standard normal distribution, but with an added parameter $\alpha$ to represent skewness, the density function is 
$$
   f(x)=2 \phi(x)\Phi(\alpha x), \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Its cdf (cumulative distribution function) an be written as 
$$
   F(x)= \Phi(x)-2 T(x,\alpha)
$$
where $T(x,\alpha)$ is the [Owen T function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function) and $\phi(x), \Phi(x)$ is the standard normal density and cdf. Using the property that $T(-x,\alpha)=T(x,\alpha)$ it is now an easy exercise to show that $X^2$ ($X$ distributed skewnormal $\alpha$) has the same distribution as $Z^2$ when $Z$ is standard normal (this is an important result in inference theory for skew normal models.)

Another way to see it is using the comment of @whuber. If $X$ is a continuous random variable with density $f$, then the absolute value $\mid X \mid$ has density $f(x)+f(-x)$ for $x>0$. So we just have to look at 
\begin{align}
   2\phi(x)\Phi(\alpha x) + 2\phi(-x)\Phi(-\alpha x) &=& 2 \phi(x)\left\{ \Phi(\alpha x)+\Phi(-\alpha x)\right\} \\
&=& 2 \phi(x) \\
&=& \phi(x)+\phi(-x) \quad \text{for $x>0$.}
\end{align}